# How to use Ionic code written in Visual Studio Code in xCode?

Tags: angular, xcode, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, hybrid-mobile-app

I created an Ionic Angular mobile app in Visual Studio Code. Now, I signed up for a virtual Mac environment macinCloud and want to create the app for iOS with XCode. I cloned my GitHub project and have the project folder on the mac but when I try to open the project folder, I get the message 'Cannot open files'.
Is there a way to import the project into XCode or do I need to rewrite the entire code again?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are your using Cordova or Capacitor? For Cordova https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/ios    For Capacitor https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app/6-deploying-mobile

Comment: I use capacitor but the issue is a different one. How can I open the project folder in xCode?

Comment: `ionic cap open ios` this will open the project in xcode.. if you still get error, you will have to delete your ios folder and run this `ionic build && ionic cap sync ios && ionic cap open ios`